# e.map is not a function error on production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, redux, production-environment

I built a little application with react and redux. It works fine on localhost. But after I deployed it on firebase it gives me this error.

[image]
I know this happens when we try to map an empty array. There is one API call in this app. It works fine on localhost.

I tried deploy same application on `surge` it gives me this error.

[image]

What is the reason for this?. Is this a problem of my code or problem of the API endpoint that I'm referring?.

Comment: why dont you `console.log("e is: " , e) ` and see if e is really an array.

Comment: Payload shown is html. You need to look in browser dev tools network and see what is happening with actual requests. Looks like you have some path issues

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka There is nothing like that in my code.

Comment: It’s not your code that is generating the html payload, it’s an error from the server that is being returned as an error “page”. The API call is simply failing in production. What does your network tab display in production for that API call? What does the html returned say?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky it says `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>`
this is my deployment url: https://smove-c721b.firebaseapp.com/dashboard

Comment: Thank you for sharing that but it won’t be enough information. Do you have access to the API? What is happening on side of the API in production for that endpoint /bookings? Any errors? Anything logging indicating an issue? Please show both the API endpoint and also the call in React.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Nope I do not have access to the backend. this is an open api endpoint.
https://challenge.smove.sg/bookings

Comment: Okay, then please at least show how you are making that call in React.